# Symfony: detect if controller request is a sub-request

Tags: php, symfony

Using http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html, how the targeted controller can know if request is coming from HTTP or from the template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have multiple ways to do that. The simpler solution is to inject the `request_stack` service, and check if `getParentRequest` is null or not. If it's null, then the request is coming from the master request.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

// ...

public function indexAction(RequestStack $requestStack)
{

    $isMasterRequest = $requestStack->getParentRequest() === null;
```

Comment: Thanks, why there is no something like ``$request->getMasterRequest()``?

Comment: `RequestStack` has a `getMasterRequest` method. The `Request` object doesn't, but you could have an event listener to add some useful attribute there in event of a sub-request.